# How to run SQL Server based database on MAC OS X?

Tags: sql-server, xampp

```
USE [web]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[academicDepartments]    Script Date: 11/30/2015 3:36:27 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[academicDepartments](
    [acdeptID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [deptName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_academicDepartments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [acdeptID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[achievements]    Script Date: 11/30/2015 3:36:27 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[achievements](
    [registrationNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [achievements] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

I have been provided a DB by my teacher that was made by him on Microsoft SQL Server. I have to ask you how am I supposed to import or run the queries on XAMPP at MAC OS X (El-Capitan)

Comment: Script you've provided - is not a DB itself, but script creating two tables `academicDepartments` and `achievements` when being executed. While you can't run it at MySQL instance of XAMPP "as is", you can create the same tables having the same columns by yourself and execute all queries you need.

Comment: Please tag your question correctly.

Comment: Actually this is just a extract from the actual code. I was unable to attach the entire .sql file here.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server doesn't run on MAC OS X, it only runs on windows; you have two options:

1. use SQL Azure in the cloud or
2. Using VirtualBox on your MAX OS X run a VM of Windows and install the evaluation edition/Express edition of SQL Server.

Comment: Let me try and use SQl Azure

Comment: SQL Azure is paid and I don't want to use SQL Server on Virtual Box is there any other way?

Comment: No. Microsoft SQL Server requires Windows, so your only other option is to use Microsoft SQL Server in the cloud (aka SQL Azure).